# Nginx write logs to the old file after running logrotate

Tags: nginx, logrotate

The logrotate config is:

```
cat /etc/logrotate.d/nginx:

/data/logs/nginx/*.log
{
daily
dateext
dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
rotate 30
missingok
create
notifempty
sharedscripts
postrotate
        [ ! -f /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`
endscript
}
```

But nginx write logs to the access.log.2016-05-15, not access.log

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www  root    0 May 14 03:46 access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www  root  47M May 16 10:26 access.log.2016-05-15
```

How should I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Doe the file which the config is relying upon (`/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`)exist ?

Comment: I worked it out finally, thanks. FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245926/nginx-write-logs-to-the-old-file-after-running-logrotate